Unable to locate Azure App Service on Azure DevOps
I have been trying to connect my Azure App Service to build a pipeline for deployment from Azure DevOps but am not able to locate my Azure App Service from Azure DevOps. I get an internal error stated with the code of TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: d187575f-c6d4-47ed-8177-da6f452b8b79.
Note - please refer to the below image for error.
Any inputs on the same would be highly appreciated, many thanks.
I tried giving my Azure App service name manually but no luck.


It seems that there may be some issues with the Service connection you are using. Could you please check whether the key in your Service connection has expired or try to create a new Service connection? You can also sign out of Azure DevOps, then open an InPrivate or incognito browser window to login Azure DevOps and try again.

It seems that there may be some issues with the Service connection you are using.
You can try the following steps:

Check whether the key in your Service connection has expired
Try to create a new Service connection
You can also sign out of Azure DevOps, then open an InPrivate or incognito browser window to login Azure DevOps and try again.

